# Rows and Columns List<List<string>> matrix;

Tags: c#

friends, I have this two-dimensional List and would like to know how I can get the number of rows and columns you have.

regards
cronos

```
List<List<string>> matrix;
```

Answer (score 5):

That is not a 2-dimensional array, so it doesn't have "rows" and "columns". It would probably be better to use `int[,]` instead of `List<List<int>>`.

But assuming you can't change the type then you can count the number of lists by using `matrix.Count`. Each of those lists could potentially have a different number of elements. If you know for sure that they all have the same number of elements then you could use `matrix[0].Count` to get the number of elements in the first list.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a 2D array, so every `List<string>` in the `List<>`could have a different number of elements. So:

```
int rows = matrix.Count;
int columnsFirst = matrix.First().Count; //and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a List of Lists, the number of columns may vary (one list may have 3 elements and another list may have 10, for example).

If the lists are exactly the same size then:

```
int cols  = matrix[0].Count;
int rows = matrix.Count;
```